# Uploading Image and Text on the same submit IN YII2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I realize that i cannot submit file and text in php on the same time.
Is there any solution in yii2 so i can send image and  text on the same submit?

Comment: Why did you realize so? Please, describe the problem clearer, because there is no limitation on file types for simultaneous upload

Answer (score 1):

What do you have in mind? What is not suitable for example:

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']);
    echo $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput();
    echo $form->field($model, 'text')->textInput();
    ActiveForm::end();
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
    echo Html::beginForm();
    echo Html::fileInput('image');
    echo Html::textInput('text');
    echo Html::endForm();
?>
```

Comment: You should add enctype attribute in begin() of form